# How to disable ToolStripMenuItem in Context menu Dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolstrip, contextmenustrip

In my windows application i have a context menu with a grid the problem is that I want to disable the ToolStripMenuItem in context menu according to the user previlages.How can i do that. i have done like this but it is not working

```
private void contextMenuStrip_Machine_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    toolStripAuthorize.Enabled = INFOpermission.accessAuthorize;
}
```

but it is not working

Comment: 1. Show us more code.
2. When you put a breakpoint after the assignment does toolStripAuthorize have Enabled set to false or true?
3. Is INFOpermission.accessAuthorize set to false when expected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You need to set `toolStripAuthorize.Enabled` to either `true` or `false`.**

I have no idea what `INFOpermission.accessAuthorize` is because you didn't show the code that defines that (enum?), but if it's anything other than `false`, this isn't going to work out like you expect.

I can guarantee that setting the [`Enabled` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.enabled.aspx) of the `ToolStripMenuItem` that you want to disable to `false` in the [`Opening` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.opening.aspx) handler *will work*. If it's not working for you, you're doing something else wrong, and you need to give us some more information to go on.

If you're stuck, see the sample code here: [How to: Handle the ContextMenuStrip Opening Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229721.aspx)

---

**EDIT:** Armed with new information provided in the comments, I've now isolated the source of the problem. You've assigned the `ContextMenuStrip` to the `RowTemplate` of a `DataGridView` control, and are therefore not able to modify items contained in that context menu in its `Opening` event handler method.

It turns out that this is a known bug that someone decided was "by design". You can see the original bug report [here on Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/140588/datagridview-has-problems-with-contextmenustrip-assigned-to-rowtemplate-property). The explanation given is that whenever a new row is created based on the `RowTemplate` (which is how the `RowTemplate` works), the `ContextMenuStrip` that you've assigned gets cloned as well. That means the same context menu instance is not used for each row, and whatever properties that you try to set on the *original* menu items have no effect.

Fortunately, it also gives us a workaround. Like all events, the `Opening` event passes the actual instance of the `ContextMenuStrip` that is about to be opened as its `sender` parameter. *This* is the context menu whose items you need to modify in order for your alterations to be visible.

**So what's the code?** It looks like this:

```
private void contextMenuStrip_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    ContextMenuStrip cmnu = (ContextMenuStrip)sender;
    cmnu.Items[1].Enabled = false;
}
```

Notice, though, that you'll have to reference the individual menu item that you want to modify by its index. This is just the zero-based position of the item in the menu that you want to modify. You can't use the `toolStripAuthorize` object like you were trying to do before because a new instance of it has been cloned for each new context menu instance.

Comment: it is returning false and value is assining also but it the toolstripmenu is showing

Comment: @NIGHIL: The *menu* is still going to open. If you want to cancel the menu opening, set `e.Cancel = true`. Setting the `Enabled` property of a particular item will cause it to appear grayed out (unselectable) in the menu. Which are you trying to do?

Comment: @Code Gray: Menu will open but the disabled item is Enabled in the menu the value of INFOpermission.accessAuthorize is false

Comment: if (INFOpermission.accessAuthorize == false)contextMenuStrip_Machine.Items.Remove(toolStripAuthorize); toolStripAuthorize is there it is not removed

Comment: @NIGHIL: So, the menu item is actually named something different than you posted in your original code? Then just set *that* to disabled. Since I can't see your screen from where I'm sitting, it's difficult to guess at what all of your controls/variables are named.

Comment: @Code Gray: i corrected it still not working

if (INFOpermission.accessAuthorize == false)
contextMenuStrip_Machine.Items.Remove(toolStripAuthorize);
 toolStripAuthorize is there it is not removed

Comment: @NIGHIL: Then, either your computer is possessed with evil spirits, or there's some part of your code I can't see that's causing the problem. Just for fun, I tested this again on my computer by creating a new project, adding a `ContextMenuStrip` with a couple of items, and disabling one in the `Opening` event. Everything worked fine.

Comment: @Code Gray: I am assigning context menu to datagrid -> rowtemplate-> contextmenustrip , will that cause any problem ?

Comment: @NIGHIL: Yes, apparently. That's the problem because I can't get that to work on my machine either. More information is always the key. Let me debug it for a minute.